# Python reading a csv file

Tags: python

I am very new to python....

There are a lot of answer on Stackoverflow regarding reading a csv file into a list and I used one to get to the following:

```
#opens the csv file and reads in the data
filepath = 'Online Retail.csv'
spent = 0
with open(filepath) as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
```

I can then loop through the `readCSV` variable and get some results out...great.  The problem I have is further through the code I want to access the readCSV list again but it is closed and I get the error:

> I/O operation on closed file.

How do  I reference the `readCSV`variable again if I need to.  Or is there a better way to import the data so it only occurs once and I can then extract whatever data I want at any point in my script?

I am using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Why not save the data in a variable and work with that?

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python with file open", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.  Very simply, when you leave the `with` block, the file gets closed.  You have to open it again.  readCSV is not a *list*: it's a generator that reads the file.  If you want to use a list of the file contents, you have to read it all and store it.  Again, see the tutorials for details.

Comment: Can you use Pandas to read CSV files?

Comment: I am going to try and get pandas working tonight

Answer (score 0):

you need to define mode (read, write or append), So, here as you reading the file hence you need read mode which is written as below `with open`:

```
with open(filepath, "r") as csvfile:
```

If csvfile is a file object, it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference.

```
with open(filepath, "rb") as csvfile:
```

Answer (score 0):

In that way, you can only access the csv file inside the `with`. The file is closed at the end of `with` block.

```
with open(filepath) as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    # you can access the file here

# you cannot access the file here
```

If you need it to access the file further down the line, you could either save it in a `list` or `dict`, or if it contains a huge amount of data, open it with pandas

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv(filepath)
```

Comment: I have seen pandas mentioned but I am having trouble installing it

Comment: If you want, we can discuss about this in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182950/pandas-installation) instead